# Can't send fpdf (php) with swiftmailer

Tags: php, pdf, attachment, swiftmailer

I have to programm a website for university.
My knowledge about php is not so good (started this semester)

I want to create a pdf file and after I saved it I want to send it as an attachment with swiftmailer.

Here is a part of my code which I wrote to send the mail with attachment.

```
require_once "../swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php"; // Swift initialisieren

include('../credentials.php');
// Create the attachment with your data
$attachment = Swift_Attachment::fromPath("Rechnung_".$_SESSION['refn'].".pdf", "application/pdf");
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "GET") {

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance(); // Ein Objekt für die Mailnachricht

$message
->setFrom(array($absenderadresse => $absendername))
->setTo(array($zieladresse))
->setSubject($betreff)
->attach ($attachment)
->setBody(
"random text");

$mailtext = "";

foreach ($_POST as $name => $wert) {
if (is_array($wert)) {
foreach ($wert as $einzelwert) {
$mailtext .= $name . $trenner . $einzelwert . "\n";
}
} else {
$mailtext .= $name . $trenner . $wert . "\n";
}
}
```

The result I get is the following

> Message-ID: <0e2c78549b70c6754d6213e28f27bc3b@dine.bronxx.org> Date: Sun, 20 Dec 2015 00:52:45 +0100 Subject: Rechnung FH Portal From: FH Portal To: na.racine@gmx.ch MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="_=_swift_v4_1450569165_894d353ae292b94f0887df24da701f46_=*" --*=_swift_v4_1450569165_894d353ae292b94f0887df24da701f46_=_ Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable  ... --_=_swift_v4_1450569165_894d353ae292b94f0887df24da701f46_=_ Content-Type: application/pdf; name=Rechnung_5000000004.pdf Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Rechnung_5000000004.pdf JVBERi0xLjM..."

EDIT:
The problem is not the code i posted bevore.

```
// Echo Logger aktivieren (es gibt noch einen logger der auf File schreibt)
$logger = new Swift_Plugins_Loggers_EchoLogger();
$mailer->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin($logger));

echo $message;
$result = $mailer->send($message);
} catch (Exception $e) {
$error_log = $logger->dump();
}

if ($result == 0) {
die("Mail konnte nicht versandt werden.");
}

header("Location: $urlDankeSeite");
exit;
}
```

It is the problem that `$result` is empty. 
I had the output because of `echo $message;`

Comment: At first sight this looks like an issue with your line breaks. Could be that it helps of you use the constant `PHP_EOL` instead of hard coded unixoid line breaks (`\n`) if the code is executed under an MS-Windows based system. For certainly the result you dumped lacks line breaks.

Comment: I have the problem with the attachment, it will change into a String and is shown in my browser. It can't be the problem with the line breaks, I used this part of the code in an other file and it works

Comment: Ah, you did not write that you get that "result" in your browser! Your code does not show any attempt to send the message, so we cannot say much... Same for why you get that stuff in your browser, your code does not show that. Might be an error raised by that class you use if you have php configured to display errors. But again: we cannot say much without additional information from your side.

Comment: I added another part of the code.

Comment: I have no experience with that specific mailing class, but `new Swift_Plugins_Loggers_EchoLogger();` sounds to me like it logs using `echo`...

Comment: I don't know what the problem was, but it solved it after I wrote the code new.... thx for your help anyway and Happy Hollidays :D

Comment: how do you fix the problem please ?